# Kerberos with i3-dmenu-desktop

Tags: arch-linux, i3, kerberos, dmenu

I use Kerberos authentication in Thunderbird, Firefox and for ssh and it works just fine if I use the programs from the shell. But when I use `i3-dmenu-desktop` to start Thunderbird and Firefox, the Kerberos ticket is not "attached".

I use `kinit` with a cache file, which is exported in my `.bashrc` (KRB5CCNAME). I do not really know how `dmenu` works. Is it normal that it does not "inherit" environment variables?

Comment: How do you start i3? From a display manager or via xinit (startx)? If the latter, you might need to exit i3, log out and start i3 again. If the former, then yes, the window manager is not launched from the shell and therefore does not have the same environment variables (cf. [LightDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#X_session_wrapper))

Comment: I use startx. Setting the environment variable before "exec i3" in .xinitrc actually works, so this is kind of a no-brainer. I wonder why I did not try it before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohannesTitz it sounds like you've found an answer; would you please write it up as such? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

stefan0xC gave the correct hints. I will answer myself after the comment by Jeff Schaller.

Just add:

`export KRB5CCNAME=path`

in your .xinitrc (before launching a window manager, in my case i3), where path is the path to the krbcache file.